# Check if a user logged in or not: Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I want to check if a user is logged in or not in drupal. If user is logged in, print something. Otherwise do nothing. I am checking it as follows:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid)
{
  echo "Logged In';
}
else
{
   echo "Not logged in";
}
```

But, in this case, it is always showing 'Not logged in' either user is logged in or not. I tried echo $user->uid also. But it is not printing anything. What can be the issue???

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use a global variable here. Simply use the [`user_is_logged_in()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) function (available for Drupal 6+).

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    echo "Logged In";
}
else {
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

Comment: I tried with this also, but it is also not returning anything. Always it is printing Not logged in only.

Comment: @prembaranwal: Is the user *actually* logged in?

Comment: Yes, definitely it is logged in

Comment: @prembaranwal: what does `print_r($user)` output?

Comment: @prembaranwal§ If the user is logged in then `user_is_logged_in()` will return true, there's nothing else that can happen unless you have a messed up installation, or you're running that code somewhere daft (e.g. in index.php before Drupal's bootstrapped).

Comment: @prembaranwal Which template file are you using this code? Page.tpl.php, node.tpl.php etc?

Answer (score 0):

All anonymous users have user_id as 0, even if they are not logged in.
Use following code to check if user is logged in.

```
global $user;
   if($user->uid!=0){
   echo "Logged In";
   }
   else{
   echo "Not logged in";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to check if a user is logged in or not in drupal. If user is logged in, print something. Otherwise do nothing. I am checking it as follows:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid==0)
{
  echo "Not Logged In';
}
else
{
   echo "Logged in";
}
```

your code gets a zero as return value which is why you are always getting logged in..